# Hibernate jpql query correct usage

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jersey, dropwizard

I am creating a `Jersey` web service with `Hibernate` and `Dropwizard`.

I wanted to ask for a correct and effective way of using them for connecting and using DB.

I have already defined the DB itself. I wanted to ask about the correct way of adding records and query the DB.

Regarding querying the DB, right now I got some simple JPQL queries in the annotaion `@NamedQueries` which is a part of the class which represents the database table. For example:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name = "Persons")
@Table(name = "Persons")
@NamedQueries(
        { 
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findAll", query = "select p from Persons p"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Person.findByEmail", query = "select p from Persons p " + "where p.personEmail like :email") 
        })

public class Person implements Serializable
{ ... }
```

When I want to query I am doing something like this:

```
public Person getPersonByEmail(String email)
{
        Person personByName = (Person) namedQuery("Person.findByEmail").setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();
        return personByName;
}
```

Is this a correct and effective way of querying the DB? should I stack queries like that in the `@NamedQueries` annotation?

Regarding to addition to the DB, I'm doing it like this for now:

```
public void insertPersonToDB()
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try
        {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Person pers = new Person("param1","param2");
            short personID = (short) session.save(pers);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

Is this also a correct and effective way of adding records to the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I want to query I am doing something like this:

```
public Person getPersonByEmail(String email){
        Person personByName = (Person) namedQuery("Person.findByEmail").setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();
        return personByName;
}
```

> Is this a correct and effective way of querying the DB? should I stack
>   queries like that in the @NamedQueries annotation?

The other approach is using `createQuery(jpqlQuery)` :

```
public Person getPersonByEmail(String email){
        Person personByName = (Person) em.createQuery(
        "select p from Persons p where p.personEmail like :email"). 
        setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();
        return personByName;
}
```

We call sometimes, queries created with `createQuery()` dynamic queries, since not compiled.
You can also use `Criteria` (full object way for creating your query) but it's more complex to write, so it's really  useful for "true" dynamic queries where some clauses of the query are added at runtime (add a condition or a join for example).

Generally, if your request has no requirement to be created in a dynamic way  (with SQL clause added at runtime), you will often be advised to use `@NameQuery` rather than `createQuery(java.lang.String jpqlString)`  since considered as more performant. Personally, I think that  it is a false good advice.

For example, in *Pro EJB 3: Java Persistence API*, you are said that `Named queries are a way of organising your static queries in a manner that is more readable, maintainable as well as performant.`

For performance, it is theoretic.
It refers to the translation from HQL to SQL. 
With `NamedQuery`, you are sure it's performed a single time.
But with `createQuery(java.lang.String jpqlString)`, the effective performance is the same or almost, if you do well the things.

First, transforming a HQL query to SQL represents almost nothing if you compare it to the cost for transmitting the query to the database, executing it and retrieving the result (sql mapping to object mapping)
Second, most of query engines (Hibernate for example) will cache the translated SQL but if you build your query as you should not : string concatenation for setting parameters of the query.

For the remain, `createQuery(java.lang.String jpqlString)` help to create a good design since it's obviously more easy to read and modify a query from where it's called than to the root of an entity.
No indirection to read it in its globability and also to see how are set the parameters in the query.
On the contrary, modifying a `JPQL` query among many other `JPQL` queries at the root of the class, which may look like and have a very near name is error-prone.

The single real advantage for `NamedQuery` is at compile-time, syntax errors in the query may be detected and so stops the build fast.

**Edit : second part of the question**

Regarding to addition to the DB, I'm doing it like this for now:

```
public void insertPersonToDB()
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try
        {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Person pers = new Person("param1","param2");
            short personID = (short) session.save(pers);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

> Is this also a correct and effective way of adding records to the DB?

Almost correct. You should log in the `catch HibernateException` for debugging purpose and you should also log and throws an exception if the rollback fails.

```
public void insertPersonToDB()
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Person pers = new Person("param1","param2");
            short personID = (short) session.save(pers);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e){
              try {
                     if (tx != null) {
                       tx.rollback();                         
                       logger.error(e);
                      }
                  } catch(Exception e2) {
                     logger.error(e2);
                     throw new RunTimeException("rollback failed", e2);
                  }
             } 
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: just about what you said that I should log if the rollback fails, do you mean log the message of the exception in the catch of the roll back? And is there some kind of special logging machenism which comes with Jersey?

Comment: I have finished the modifications. Yes you should log the information because it is a problem. You also  should throw an exception to signal it.
 For logging in general, Jersey is not relevant. Look at slf4j as API and log4j or logback for implementation.

Comment: by the way, in the first part you used em.createQuery(...). What is em?

Comment: em-> entityManager (comes from JPA)
It's like session in Hibernate but it's the standard interface for ORM.